# oledbexception object invalid or no longer set in MSAccess 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I am creating small Inventory application using Microsoft Access 2010 as data source.  My connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
      connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\nityaprakash\Documents\NPSInventory.accdb"
      providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

But when updating any record getting error **Object Invalid or no longer set**.  I am using OleDbCommand to update record where passing simple update query as CommandType.Text.

```
   try
    {
       _dataAccess = DataAccess.GetInstance())

            _dataAccess.OpenConnection();

            string command_ = "UPDATE Inventory SET Item = 'MyItem', Description = 'Desc', Category = '', Location = '', Manufacturer = 'CELLo', Model = 'cell101', ReorderLevel = 10, TargetStockLevel = 200, BalanceQuantity =150, Discontinued = 0, Comments = 'Comment' Where ID = 9;";
            IDbCommand cmd_ = _dataAccess.GetCommandFor(command_, CommandType.Text);

            cmd_.ExecuteNonQuery();



    }
    finally
    {
        if (_dataAccess != null)
            _dataAccess.CloseConnection();
    }
```

Comment: Post your record `updating` code here.